# deleting attributes from ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm migrating data between two activerecord connections, I've got my models all setup correctly so I can read from say Legacy::Tablename and Tablename and insert it into the new table.

The problem I have is my new model doesn't have all of the attributes that are in the legacy model so I get an 'unknown attribute' when I try to create a record in the new model via;

```
legacy_users = Legacy::User.all
legacy_users.each do |legacy_user|
  User.create legacy_user.attributes
end
```

however if I try to remove the offending attribute it still doesn't work eg.

```
legacy_user.attributes.delete 'some_attribute'
```

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: Do you have to use ActiveRecord, or can you use plain old SQL instead? It would be much faster to dump/load the data from/to the database directly instead of instantiating, validating and saving ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in that case:

```
legacy_users = Legacy::User.all
legacy_users.each do |legacy_user|
  u = User.new

  u.attributes.each do |k, v|
    old_val = legacy_user.send(k) # Get the attr from old user
    u.send("#{k}=", old_val) # Set it to the new user
  end
end
```

You won't need to go through the mess of removing each unused attribute too

Comment: that returns 'NameError: method `some_attribute' not defined in Legacy::User'

Comment: I posted an alternative response!

Comment: yep, that works great - it's going to be a combination of your answer and Deepaks since sometimes attributes are in the old model that aren't in the new model and vice versa.

Answer (score 11):

How about attributes.except(:some_attribute)?

Comment: On rails 4 this should be: attributes.except('some_attribute')

Comment: Rails [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) works, [attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) returns hash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a migration as well, and in my case I was passing a block to `first_or_create` to clone objects. I couldn't get `delete()` or `except()` to work, but for some reason this works:

`scrubbed_obj = my_obj.attributes.reject { |k,v| k == 'the_attribute_you_dont_want' }`

`new_object.attributes = scrubbed_obj`

and then the block saves fine. Just throwing dropping this answer here in case anyone else is experiencing similar issues.